# CloudKit + Core Data: How to write or read the public database only

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, cloudkit

I have a record type that is in both the Public database configuration schema and the private database configuration schema.

when I write a record type using the PersistentStore.shared.context it writes the record to both the private database and the public database. When I query the record type using @FetchRequest, it returns the records from both the public and private database.

How do I write or read to just the public or just the private database?

My PersistentStore Stack is basically a copy paste from apples WWDC code:

```
class PersistentStore: ObservableObject {
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext { persistentContainer.viewContext }
    
    // One line singleton
    static let shared = PersistentStore()
    
    private let persistentStoreName: String = "XXXX"
    let containerIdentifier: String = "iCloud.com.XXXX.XXXX"
    
    // MARK: - Core Data stack
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        //let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: persistentStoreName)
        // OR - Include the following line for use with CloudKit - NSPersistentCloudKitContainer
        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: persistentStoreName)
        
        // Enable history tracking
        // (to facilitate previous NSPersistentCloudKitContainer's to load as NSPersistentContainer's)
        // (not required when only using NSPersistentCloudKitContainer)
        guard let persistentStoreDescriptions = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
            fatalError("\(#function): Failed to retrieve a persistent store description.")
        }
        let storesURL = persistentStoreDescriptions.url!.deletingLastPathComponent()
        
        //private database
        let privateStoreURL = storesURL.appendingPathComponent("\(persistentStoreName)-private.sqlite")
        let privateStoreDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: privateStoreURL)
        privateStoreDescription.configuration = "Private"
        privateStoreDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: containerIdentifier)
        privateStoreDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
        privateStoreDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
        privateStoreDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions?.databaseScope = .private
        
        //public database
        let publicStoreURL = storesURL.appendingPathComponent("\(persistentStoreName)-public.sqlite")
        let publicStoreDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: publicStoreURL)
        publicStoreDescription.configuration = "Public"
        publicStoreDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: containerIdentifier)
        publicStoreDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions?.databaseScope = .public
        
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [publicStoreDescription, privateStoreDescription]
        
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
            }
        })
        
        // Include the following line for use with CloudKit - NSPersistentCloudKitContainer
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        // Include the following line for use with CloudKit and to set your merge policy, for example...
        
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        
        return container
    }()
    
    // Mark the class private so that it is only accessible through the singleton `shared` static property
    private init() {}
    
    // MARK: - Core Data Saving and "other future" support (such as undo)
    
    func save() {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Customize this code block to include application-specific recovery steps.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement: My app uses CloudKit & Core Data with the private and the shared database, and the entities (`Item` or `Place`) are assigned to both stores, but only one of them must be used at a time.
To handle this, I use a `var currentlyUsedStores` that is set either to the private persistent store or the shared persistent store.
New entities are initialized either in the `viewContext` or a `backgroundContext`, but before the context is saved, the context sends a notification:

```
// Register for notifications that the view context will save.
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
                                       selector: #selector(viewContextOrBackgroundContextWillSave), 
                                       name: .NSManagedObjectContextWillSave,
                                       object: viewContext)

// Register for notifications that the background context will save.
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
                                       selector: #selector(viewContextOrBackgroundContextWillSave), 
                                       name: .NSManagedObjectContextWillSave,
                                       object: backgroundContext)

 @objc func viewContextOrBackgroundContextWillSave(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let context = notification.object as? NSManagedObjectContext  else { return }
    let inserts = context.insertedObjects
    let itemsAndPlaces = inserts.filter({ $0 is Item || $0 is Place })
    itemsAndPlaces.forEach({ context.assign($0, to: currentlyUsedStores.first!) })
}
```

Since `assign` can be used before a newly inserted object is saved, all new objects are now stored only in the currently used persistent store.

To fetch only from the currently used store, the `affectedStores` property has to be set in the fetch request, e.g.

```
let itemFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: Item.entityName)
itemFetchRequest.affectedStores = currentlyUsedStores
```

If one then switches the currently used store (that can also be saved, e.g. in the user defaults, one has only to update `var currentlyUsedStores`.

**EDIT:**
A `NSBatchInsertRequest` is also executed by a `NSManagedContext`. Thus, as long as objects are newly inserted in the context, they can be assigned to the relevant persistent store in the same way.

Comment: this works. didn't use the notifications but can see how it would be useful if u wanted all the writes to be assigned to a certain store. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use assign to choose what store to save the new object to

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506436-assign

For requests from/to a certain store you can use affectedStores

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506518-affectedstores

Note you might have better luck creating 2 configurations in your model editor for public and private and assigning a different entity to each. Then it automatically saves and fetches from the entity’s corresponding store.

Comment: assign seems to work for writing. is there a way to do this with NSBatchInsertRequest? we don't get the NSManagedObjects until after the batch insert is done? so I'd have to iterate through all the objects and update them post creation which I guess would defeat the purpose of a batch insert.

Comment: Use affectedStores for requests